# Optimizing code where "problems" are in libc

Tags: performance, optimization, intel-vtune

I have a C++ code and I am playing with Intel's VTune and I ran the [General Exploration analysis](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/amplifier/lin/ug_docs/GUID-F8942544-BE61-4874-ABB7-DD70EEACC8D6.htm#GUID-F8942544-BE61-4874-ABB7-DD70EEACC8D6) and have no idea how to interpret the results. It flags as an issue the number of [Retire Stalls](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/amplifier/lin/ug_docs/GUID-8A9C663C-B465-432D-8302-E74BE6FFDE42.htm).

On it's own, that is enough to confuse me because I'm probably in over my head. But the functions that it lists as having an abnormal amount of retire stalls is `_int_malloc` and `malloc_consolidate`, both in `libc`. So it's not even something that I can look at my own code and try to figure out and it's not something that I can really begin to change.

Is there a way to use that information to improve my own code? Or does it really just mean that I should find ways to allocate less or less often?

(Note: the specific code at hand isn't the issue, I'm looking for strategies to interpret the data and improve things when the hotspots or the stalls or whatever the "problem" may be occurs in code outside my control)

Comment: Memory is slow, a cache miss can easily cost as much as 200 cpu cycles with the processor stalled.  Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: It shows that there are a lot of Retire Stalls in those functions, but it might not be the actual hotspot in terms of overall performance. I would recommend you to do Advanced Hotspots analysis and sort by CPU_CLK_UNHALTED counter, which will show you how many cycles did you spend in each function.

Comment: I usually change to "Hardware Event Sample Count" viewpoint to analyze hotspots.

Comment: @Elalfer Sorted by CPU_CLK_UNHALTED shows these two same functions as the highest counts. 163.2 million counts, 140.4 million counts respectively. The 3rd highest is a function in my own code at 90 million counts

Comment: @tpg2114 R U sure you are looking @ "Sample Counts"? You should collect enough samples (run workload for at least few seconds) to estimate how much time have you spent in each function.

If malloc is a real hotspot your probably want to restructure your code to do less memory allocations/objects creation.

Comment: @Elalfer Yes, I'm looking at sample counts and the code runs for 16 seconds so that's an adequate number of samples. It's entirely possible I do too much allocating/deallocating which is what I think these results are hinting at

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to use that information to improve my own code? Or does
>   it really just mean that I should find ways to allocate less or less
>   often?

**Yes**, it pretty much sounds like you should make changes in *your* code so that malloc gets called less often.

- Is the heap allocation really necessary?
- Is there a buffer that you can reuse?
- Is using [memory pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost/fast_pool_allocator.html) an option?
- Can you do stack allocation instead? For example, if those are
  arrays, do you happen to know the maximum size of those arrays at
  compile time?

Depending on your application, memory allocation can be expensive. I once made a program 20x faster by removing memory allocations from a tight loop. The application wasn't that slow on Linux but it was a disaster on Windows. After my changes, it was also OK on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

- know which line of code is calling malloc mostly
- avoid repeated allocation and deallocation
- potentially use thread-local-storage together with the previous point
- write your own allocator which only returns memory when you tell him to and otherwise keeps freed memory blocks in a list (use list::splice to move list elements from one list into another)
- use allocators from boost which potentially do the same like the previous point